# Comparing individual characters in a string and accepting an input to be true even if the spelling is not exact

Tags: python, string

I'm learning Python, and I have a question.

To learn, I decided to make a simple quiz program which utilizes functions and classes and stuff, as practice.

I have a question which has been bothering me a lot. The format of the quiz typically is that I ask a random question from a set of questions, and the answer needs to be typed. If the answer returned is correct, I return a True value and use that to add to the total points tally.

Now, the problem is that the string needs to be exact, otherwise even with the right intentions, the answer will be wrong. I solved this problem initially by using a set in the class arguments while defining the question, so if the answer belongs in the set, then it will be expected.

The problem with this method is, I don't quite know how a person might misspell something. For example- If the answer to a question is 'lovegood', I want to accept the answer even if the user inputs 'lovegod' or 'lovegd' or 'lovegooood', or 'lovegod', and I can't account for every single possible mispelling.

I decided that I'll write a special function that takes each and every character in the string that is inputted and compare it with each and every character in the string that is the right answer, and if the majority of the characters match, then the answer is correct. Is this something I can do, if so, how? Is there a better method?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The simplest solution I can think of is counting errors and if they don't exceed some acceptable threshold, treat answer as valid.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a very easy problem to solve elegantly as it's somewhat subjective. Where would we define the line of what's close enough and what's not?

e.g. is `lovegoodddddddddd`, `loveeeeee good` acceptable? Like you said, there are too many cases to consider.

One crude solution would be to use [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) which is an algorithm that determines how many characters in a given string differ from another string. You could define a threshold of how close of an answer you would accept.

Comment: I'd say loveeee good is something that would be a very difficult mistake to make unless the keyboard is broken. :P. Lovegod or lovegoood is a more probably 'mistake' that might occur, no?

Comment: Correct, I'm simply illustrating that it's rather subjective to make that differentiation.